# Arduino - what's a correct way to handle an array of structs?

Tags: c++, string, struct, arduino, malloc

I've got a problem while trying to fill an array with structs of Strings. Probably, I'm missing something basic in working with pointers or memory allocation rules on Arduino.

See my code below.

Data struct to be filled:

```
struct SMSData {
   String id;   
   String status;
   String from;
   String date;
   String text;
};
```

String parser routine:

```
SMSData* readSMS(String reply) {
  debugSerial.println(reply);

  // declare a pointer to result array
  SMSData* smsArray = NULL;

  const String startPattern = F("+CMGL: ");

  int index = -1;

  // calculate result array length
  byte count = 0;
  do {
    index = reply.indexOf(startPattern, (index + 1));

    if(index < 0) {
      break;
    }

    count++;
  } while(true);

  if(count == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }

  debugSerial.println(count);

  // allocate memory to store result array
  smsArray = malloc(count * sizeof(SMSData*));

  if(smsArray == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // start parsing input String
  index = reply.indexOf(startPattern);

  int fromIndex = 0;
  while(true) {
    debugSerial.println();

    if(index < 0) {
      break;
    }

    // init data for the next element of result array
    SMSData smsData = {"", "", "", "", ""};

    // start filling result array element
    // get id
    fromIndex = index + startPattern.length();
    index = reply.indexOf(F(","), fromIndex);
    smsData.id = reply.substring(fromIndex, index);

    debugSerial.println(smsData.id);

    // get status
    fromIndex = reply.indexOf(F("\""), index) + 1;
    index = reply.indexOf(F("\""), fromIndex);
    smsData.status = reply.substring(fromIndex, index);

    debugSerial.println(smsData.status);

    // get phone
    fromIndex = reply.indexOf(F("\""), index + 1) + 1;
    index = reply.indexOf(F("\""), fromIndex);
    smsData.from = reply.substring(fromIndex, index);    

    debugSerial.println(smsData.from);

    // get date
    fromIndex = reply.indexOf(F("\""), index + 1) + 1;
    index = reply.indexOf(F("\""), fromIndex);
    smsData.date = reply.substring(fromIndex, index);

    debugSerial.println(smsData.date);

    // get text
    fromIndex = index + 1;
    index = reply.indexOf(startPattern, fromIndex);

    if(index < 0) {
      smsData.text = reply.substring(fromIndex);
    } else {
      smsData.text = reply.substring(fromIndex, index);
    }

    smsData.text.trim();
    debugSerial.println(smsData.text);

    // add filled element to result array
    smsArray[count - 1] = smsData;
  }

  return smsArray;
}
```

Output parsed data:

```
SMSData* smsArray = readSMS(reply);

int count = sizeof(smsArray);

debugSerial.print(F("SMS count:"));
debugSerial.println(count);

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  SMSData smsData = smsArray[i];

  debugSerial.print(F("id: "));
  debugSerial.println(smsData.id);
  debugSerial.print(F("status: "));
  debugSerial.println(smsData.status);
  debugSerial.print(F("from: "));
  debugSerial.println(smsData.from);
  debugSerial.print(F("date: "));
  debugSerial.println(smsData.date);
  debugSerial.print(F("text: "));
  debugSerial.println(smsData.text);
}

free(smsArray);
```

Dummy String to parse:

```
String reply = "+CMGL: 1,\"REC READ\",\"+123456789012\",,\"2017/09/26,18:31:25+03\"\r\nHi\r\n+CMGL: 2,\"REC READ\",\"+123456789012\",,\"2017/09/26,18:34:25+03\"\r\nHello\r\n";
```

When I run the sketch it's output is often different, but always broken and incomplete, e.g.

```
+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","+123456789012",,"2017/09/26,18:31:25+03"
Hi
+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","+123456789012",,"2017/09/26,18:34:25+03"
Hello

2

1
REC READ
+12345678905+03 017/09/26,18:31:25+03
Hi

2
REC REA
```

As you can see according to the output, it logs out the whole input string, starts parsing it, goes through the first loop iteration (mixing strings from struct fields), starts the second iteration filling struct with heavily mixed Strings once again and then stops responding in the middle of it.

Right now I see no reason for such behaviour except the problems with memory allocation, but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

Any your help is appreciated.

Comment: What is (the definition of) `String` and `F(...)`?

Comment: @Yunnosch String is a standard Arduino data type (description - https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject, source - https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.h), F is macro for storing string value in flash memory (see the same header file for define).

Comment: `reply` is a String variable, see it's declaration and initialization in my post.

Comment: In `int count = sizeof(smsArray);` I think that count gets to be much higher than you expect, it is the size in bytes of smsArray.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, I missed the line with the definition of `reply`.

Comment: Speaking about the `count` - I thought the same, but in practice `sizeof(smsArray)` gives me 2 and `sizeof(smsArray) / sizeof(SMSData)` gives 0. Nevertheless, it seems that the code now hangs on execution _before_ leaving readSMS method, so the `count` shouldn't be taken into account.)

Comment: Is the following possible? The count is too high, your program gets fatal error accessing beyond the array and hangs. The output stops in the middle of what is still valid result, because the output is asynchronous and slower.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155497/discussion-between-vyacheslav-orlovsky-and-yunnosch).

Comment: You need to find the number of entries other than looking at the size of smsArray (it is always 4, being a pointer). The size of the malloced memory pointed to is unknown outside of the parser function.

Comment: `smsArray = malloc(count * sizeof(SMSData*));` is allocating room for `count` pointers to `SMSData`, that's not what you want for an actual array. It should be `smsArray = malloc(count * sizeof *smsArray);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is c++, not strictly c, that's okay, but the tag should be changed.  Here are some problems I found in your code...

```
    ///// Passing nothing, println requires one or two parameters
    debugSerial.println();
```

See [documentation on println](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println)

```
    // init data for the next element of result array
    ////// You are creating a local buffer, it will go out of scope
    ////// when you leave the function.  And you are trying to store
    ////// it in an array that you return from your function.
    ////// And you are changing the data with pass through your loop
    ////// (2 passes).
    SMSData smsData = {"", "", "", "", ""};

    //...
    ////// You should be assigning an allocated struct pointer
    ////// count is not changing, you are only assigning the last
    ////// element of the array.
    smsArray[count - 1] = smsData;


///// This will not work.  smsArray is a pointer and you have lost
///// the information about how much memory was allocated and assigned to
///// the pointer.
SMSData* smsArray = readSMS(reply);
int count = sizeof(smsArray);
```

One trick we use to use with C style pointers as arrays, was to allocate a block of pointers one bigger than we needed, and make sure they were all set to NULL (using calloc() instead of malloc()).  Then, we would set eacch pointer in the array except the last one.  Finally, we would iterate through the array until the pointer was NULL, indicating the end of the data.

You should be storing pointers to allocated data in your smsArray, and you should free (destroy) the that data as well as the array.

So, your code might look something like...

```
SMSData** smsArray = NULL;
smsArray = (SMSData **)calloc(count+1, sizeof(SMSData *));
int idx = 0;
//...

    SMSData* smsData = new smsData();
    smsData->id = ""; //etc. for the rest of the fields
    //...

    smsArray[idx++] = smsData;
    //..
```

After return...

```
SMSData ** smsArray = readSMS(reply);
SMSData ** ptr = smsArray;
while (ptr != NULL) {
    //do stuff with ptr->whatever
    destroy(ptr); //destroy since allocated with new
    ptr++;
}
free(smsArray); //free since allocated with malloc
```

This is not the best code (and may have bugs, I don't have access to my compiler right now).  But it tries to stick with your approach.

Comment: I got it - should 1) use an array of pointers and 2) allocate a new struct in every loop. And speaking about `Serial.println` - I can't find the source code of it for now, but.... it works even without any arguments passed.

Comment: println may be okay, but I included the document link in my answer and it shows one or two parameters.  the compile is probably terminating arguments with a NULL, and so it "just so happens" to work

Comment: Arduino documentation is very basic, you might agree.  I've just found the declaration at https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.h - `size_t println(void)` is there also.